undefined variable in laravel blade
i have a blade page in laravel project has for each loop in first div class that has fetch data from controller and loop in the table but also i have called that variable after foreach function in edit div modal class it shows
Undefined variable $matumizi
first div
<div class="table-responsive table-card mt-3 mb-1">
       <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="myDataTable">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th scope="col">#</th>
                     <th scope="col">Aina ya Matumizi</th>
                     <th scope="col">Maelezo Yake</th>
                     <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
               <tbody>
                    @php
                    $i=1;
                    @endphp
                     @foreach ($ainamatumizi as $matumizi)
                     <tr>
                      <td>{{ $i++}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $matumizi->name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $matumizi->description }}</td>
                      <td>

    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" title="Edit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#showModal-edit"
                                    <i class="bx bx-edit"></i> Edit
                                </button>

                                <form action="{{ route('ainamatumizi.destroy', $matumizi->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
                                    @csrf
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');">
                                        <i class="bx bx-trash"></i> Delete
                                    </button>
                                </form>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

the div for edit which variable $matumizi is undefined is below
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal-edit" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update the Details</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form id="editForm" action="{{ route('ainamatumizi.update')}}" method="PUT">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="editName" class="form-label">Name of Expenditure</label>
<input type="text" id="editName" value="{{$matumizi->name}}" class="form-control" name="name" required />

                    <label for="editDescription" class="form-label">Description of Expenditure</label>
                    <input type="text" id="editDescription" value="{{$matumizi->description}}"class="form-control" name="description" required />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="hstack gap-2 justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I expected the variable $matumizi to be identified in the edit div class since it was created in the first div of table and they are on the same page

the first $matumizi got its value from the iteration of $ainamatumizi in the @foreach loop. So the $matumizi variable in the edit modal is undefined unless you explicitly pass its value from your Controller. You can try moving the whole edit modal <div> into the @foreach loop, right after the Edit button. Let me know if it works or not :)

this work fine but if you have items more than one from the table is displaying item details of the last item in the table even if you want to select item of first in the list

Can you please edit the question and share your current code and maybe some screenshots so others could give better suggestions?
